# Non-greedy string regular expression matching

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here, but I cannot make R to use non-greedy regular expressions:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_match('xxx aaaab yyy', "a.*?b")                                         
     [,1]   
[1,] "aaaab"
```

Base functions behave the same way:

```
> regexpr('a.*?b', 'xxx aaaab yyy')
[1] 5
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 5
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

I would expect the match to be just `ab` as per 'greedy' comment in http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html:

> By default repetition is greedy, so the maximal possible number of repeats is used. 
>       This can be changed to ‘minimal’ by appending ? to the quantifier. (There are further 
>       quantifiers that allow approximate matching: see the TRE documentation.)

Could someone please explain me what's going on?

**Update.** What's crazy is that in some other cases non-greedy patterns behave as expected:

```
> str_match('xxx <a href="abc">link</a> yyy <h1>Header</h1>', '<a.*>')
     [,1]                                          
[1,] "<a href=\"abc\">link</a> yyy <h1>Header</h1>"
> str_match('xxx <a href="abc">link</a> yyy <h1>Header</h1>', '<a.*?>')
     [,1]              
[1,] "<a href=\"abc\">"
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Difficult concept so I'll try my best... Someone feel free to edit and explain better if it is a bit confusing.

Expressions that match your patterns are searched from left to right. Yes, all of the following strings `aaaab`, `aaab`, `aab`, and `ab` are matches to your pattern, but `aaaab` being the one that starts the most to the left is the one that is returned.

So here, your non-greedy pattern is not very useful. Maybe this other example will help you understand better when a non-greedy pattern kicks in:

```
str_match('xxx aaaab yyy', "a.*?y") 
#      [,1]     
# [1,] "aaaab y"
```

Here all of the strings `aaaab y`, `aaaab yy`, `aaaab yyy` matched the pattern and started at the same position, but the first one was returned because of the non-greedy pattern.

---

So what can you do to catch that last `ab`? Use this:

```
str_match('xxx aaaab yyy', ".*(a.*b)")
#      [,1]        [,2]
# [1,] "xxx aaaab" "ab"
```

How does it work? By adding a greedy pattern `.*` in the front, you are now forcing the process to put the last possible `a` into the captured group.

Comment: Thanks @floder - I completely forgot that it always start matching from the left. People have being discussing it for a long time: http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl6.language.regex/2000/12/msg507.html

Answer (score 10):

The **problem** is *matching the shortest window between two strings*. @flodel correctly mentions that a regex engine is parsing the string from left to right, and thus all the matches are *leftmost*. Greediness and laziness only apply to the boundaries on the right: greedy quantifiers get the substrings up to the rightmost boundaries, and the lazy ones will match up to the first occurrence of the subpatterns to follow.

See the **examples**:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract('xxx aaaab yyy', "a[^ab]*b")
[1] "ab"
> str_extract('xxx aaa xxx aaa zzz', "xxx.*?zzz")
[1] "xxx aaa xxx aaa zzz"
> str_extract('xxx aaa xxx aaa zzz', "xxx(?:(?!xxx|zzz).)*zzz")
[1] "xxx aaa zzz"
```

The first and the third scenarios return the shortest window, the second one is an illustration of the current problem but with a multicharacter input.

**Scenario 1. Boundaries are single characters**

In case `a` and `b` are single characters, the shortest window is found by using a negated character class. `a[^ab]*b` will easily grab the substring from `a` till the next `b` with no `a`s and `b`s in between.

**Scenario 2. Boundaries are not single characters**

You may use a [*tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) in these cases that can be further unrolled. The `xxx(?:(?!xxx|zzz).)*zzz` pattern matches `xxx`, then any 0+ chars other than a linebreak char that is not the starting char of a `xxx` or `zzz` char sequence (the `(?!xxx|zzz)` is a *negative lookahead* that fails the match if the substring immediately to the right matches the lookahead pattern), and then a `zzz`.

These *matching* scenarios can be easily used with base R `regmatches` (using a PCRE regex flavor that supports lookaheads):

```
> x <- 'xxx aaa xxx aaa zzz xxx bbb xxx ccc zzz'
> unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("xxx(?:(?!xxx|zzz).)*zzz", x, perl = TRUE)))
[1] "xxx aaa zzz" "xxx ccc zzz"
```

One note: when using a PCRE regex in base R, or the ICU regex in `str_extract`/`str_match`, the `.` does not match linebreak characters, to enable that behavior, you need to add `(?s)` at the pattern start (an inline DOTALL modifier).