# Regex for multi line search that should select text "abc" which comes before the text "xyz" and should not select anything except "abc"

Tags: regex, preg-match, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Regex for multi line search that should select text "abc" which comes before the text "xyz" and should not select anything except "abc"

suppose if the text is as below,

```
    aaaabbbb
    abc
     abc
 lmn xyz
```

the regex should match only the text abc in 3rd line just above last line

Comment: And where is your code? Have You even tried anything?

Comment: Aha, you want to match the shortest window between the value you need and some text after it. You need to use a tempered greedy token. [This answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40556433/3832970) (for an ICU regex flavor that is similar to PCRE) can throw some light on how this is done. Please try on your own based on that, and come back if you fail to get the result you need.

Comment: No, this scenario is for multi line search

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following:

```
/.*(abc).*xyz/s
```

Please note the s option which makes this work across multiple lines by just using .* to skip both regular characters and new lines

Comment: No, this regex is selecting all text

Comment: No, this regex is matching the entire text, but the text abc you require appears in the first matching group from where you should retrieve the result.

Comment: i want this to happen in one regex