# js regex to select all words between 2 words with no overlap

Tags: regex

the following js regex:

```
the(.*?)study
```

selects all words between the words 'the' and 'study', e.g.:

***the** assumption that ACE levels are stable, circulating ACE has been shown to be altered in obesity and weight loss. We sought to examine effects of a high-saturated-fat (HF) diet on ACE within **the NUtriGenomic Analysis in Twins (NUGAT) study**.

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/qn988d/1%20example)

how can I select the words between 'the' and 'study' without overlapping, i.e.:

**the** NUtriGenomic Analysis in Twins (NUGAT) **study**.

Comment: In the regex, when you put `.*` before `the`, the capturing group will only match `NUtriGenomic Analysis in Twins (NUGAT)`. You can also modify your regex to `.*the\s*(.*?)\s*study` in order to remove spaces from the match.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40556433/3832970). Your pattern can be written as `the((?:(?!the).)*?)study` or `the((?:(?!the|study).)*)study`

Comment: @ Wiktor "Non-greedy string regular expression matching" is fairly a esoteric and cannot be found using search criteria such as select all words/strings between 2 words. But thank you for linking it.