# Regex minimal match

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

I'm trying to write a regex in Python that will match a single sentence (from `.` to `.`) containing a specific word.
The regex I wrote is `r"\..*?hello.*?\."`. As you can see I'm using the non-greedy quantifier.
The text I'm matching against is:

`This is the 1st sentence. This is the 2nd. This is the 3rd, hello,  world. This is the 4th.`

(here's a [link](https://regex101.com/r/9vt14W/1/) to regex101)

I'd like the match to be `This is the 3rd, hello,  world.` , but though the `*?` quantifier is non-greedy, the match includes also the 2nd sentence. What am I missing?

Comment: `\.[^.]*hello.*?\.` or `\.[^.]*hello[^.]*\.` would do, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21478871/3832970

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please post this as an answer! :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks! that's perfect!

Comment: My answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577432/non-greedy-string-regular-expression-matching/40556433#40556433)